# adjust date range of bootstrap datepicker dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I need help to adjust date range of date picker dynamically based on data-value selected on dropdown list. I've tried with code i written below but it just didnt work.

I use bootstrap, jquery, and bootstrap datepicker.

Here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plug/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plug/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css"/>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plug/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plug/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plug/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<?php
$data[0] = array("id"=>"2", "name" => "Anton", "date_start" => "2016-10-04", "date_end" => "2016-10-14");
$data[1] = array("id"=>"4", "name" => "Boby", "date_start" => "2016-10-09", "date_end" => "2016-10-29");
$data[2] = array("id"=>"5", "name" => "Ciara", "date_start" => "2016-10-01", "date_end" => "2016-10-31");
$data[3] = array("id"=>"6", "name" => "Don", "date_start" => "2016-10-05", "date_end" => "2016-12-31");
$data[4] = array("id"=>"7", "name" => "Ester", "date_start" => "2016-10-01", "date_end" => "2016-12-31");
?>

<section class="content">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal mt-20" method="post" action="action/input">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select name="date" class="form-control select2" id="date" data-placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                            <option disabled selected>Select name</option>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($data as $r) {
                                echo "<option value='$r[id]' data-value=\"{'date_start'='$r[date_start]', 'date_end'='$r[date_end]'}\">$r[name]</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Start Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" class="form-control pull-right">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">End Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input id="end_date" name="end_date" type="text" class="form-control pull-right">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-footer col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-10">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="history.go(-1)">Cancel</button>
        </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#date').change(function () {
            var start = $(this).find(":selected").data("value").start_date;
            var end = $(this).find(":selected").data("value").end_date;

            $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                startDate: start,
                endDate: end,
                autoclose: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please modify your HTML little bit to form `<option>` like:

```
<option value='2' data-date_start="2016-10-04" data-date_end="2016-10-14">Anton</option>
```

Here `date_start` and `date_end` sits in two different attributes and hence easy to grab it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var start = null;
  var end = null;
  $('#date').change(function() {

    start = $(this).find(":selected").data("date_start");
    end = $(this).find(":selected").data("date_end");
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker("remove"); //clearing the previos options and again initiating datepicker
    initDatePicker();
  });

  function initDatePicker() {
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
      format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      startDate: new Date(start),
      endDate: new Date(end),
      autoclose: false
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<section class="content">
  <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal mt-20" method="post" action="action/input">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select name="date" class="form-control select2" id="date" data-placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
              <option disabled selected>Select name</option>
              <option value='2' data-date_start="2016-10-04" data-date_end="2016-10-14">Anton</option>
              <option value='4' data-date_start="2016-10-09" data-date_end="2016-10-29">Boby</option>
              <option value='5' data-date_start="2016-10-01" data-date_end="2016-10-31">Ciara</option>
              <option value='6' data-date_start="2016-10-05" data-date_end="2016-10-22">Don</option>
              <option value='7' data-date_start="2016-10-01" data-date_end="2016-10-17">Ester</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Start Date</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" class="form-control pull-right">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">End Date</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input id="end_date" name="end_date" type="text" class="form-control pull-right">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-footer col-md-offset-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-10">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="history.go(-1)">Cancel</button>
    </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: how if I want the end_date should be after the start_date? so if I select October 14 for the start_date, at the end_date cannot select dates before October 14. Can you help me? @vijayP